Move a QLabel with QPropertyAnimation based upon Qpoint on a QGridLayout in PyQT6
I am currently working on a piece of software made in python using the PyQT graphical framework. That requires the movement of a QLabel in a QGridlayout to another position in said gridlayout, and it is important that it is an animated movement, hence i landed on using a QPropertyAnimation.
Here is a piece of code which shows of my scenario:
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")
        self.varlayout = QGridLayout()
        self.varlayout.addWidget(QLabel("Hello World"),1,1)
        self.varlayout.addWidget(QLabel("Hello World"),2,2)
        self.varlayout.addWidget(QLabel("Hello World"),3,3)
        
        Move = QPushButton("Move",self)
        Move.clicked.connect(self.MoveLabel)
        self.varlayout.addWidget(Move,3,1)
    
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(self.varlayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def MoveLabel(self):
        self.child = self.varlayout.itemAtPosition(1,1).widget()
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.child, b"pos")
        self.anim.setDuration(500)
        Pos = QPoint(3,1)
        self.anim.setEndValue(Pos)
        self.anim.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()

The result of this codeblock is the following:

What I imagined the MoveLabel method to do is this:

What it does instead:

What I found by diging through the docs is that a Qpoint is sometimes used as a vector, which I think it is doing in this scenario, but at the same time it does not seem to follow mathematical rules of vectors according to how the grid is laid out
Which makes me think that the Qpoint refers to the Pixel location from the upper left corner.
In addition,to my knowledge, a cell in a grid layout does not exist until it is populated, but then I run into a problem how to move a object to an empty cell during runtime if it does not exist in the first place.
So right now I am at a crossroads of:

Am I using Qpoint incorrectly in the code?
Am I not supposed to use Qpoint in this scenario?
Is there another way of doing what I want to achieve?

Any help is greatly appreciated since I need to solve the exactly problem in a program written in C++, hence the use of PyQt6 here.

The pos() of widgets is in pixel coordinates, not in grid layout row/columns. I don't know what makes you think that it would be based on the layout, but it doesn't make a lot of sense: what if you used a vertical/horizontal layout, which only has one dimension? What about layouts that do not have the concept of row or column (such as stacked layouts)? Besides, what you want to achieve is not as simple as you may believe: the layout has to consider all its contents in order to set their geometries, meaning that you cannot just "move" an object around: what if the label is much bigger?

Thanks for the clarification regarding that the Position of a widget is in pixel coordinates. The reasoning for not using a vertical/horizontal layout is due to the elements will be moving in diagonal line in a form of wheel. The labels would have their own dedicated field where they would move around, hence my disregard of the problem "What if the label is much bigger?".  In the case that you recommend me using a stacked layout to solve my problem, then I might just do that instead of torturing myself with a grid layout

Sorry, I believe you misunderstood me: the question about using a vertical/horizontal or stacked layout is not intended for your specific case, but as a question to yourself about how using 2d coordinates would not make sense in those cases (which would not, for obvious reasons). And you cannot disregard the "bigger label" problem: displayed text has very different metrics depending on the font and the contents: a label with 10 "W" will be much bigger than one with 10 "I". Still, doing this, as said, is not as simple as you thought. It's slightly easier if all elements have uniform »

» sizes, because the overall layout geometry won't change. But if those elements are not all identical, then you have a much bigger problem. For instance, consider a 3x3 grid, with two "WWWWW" item in the first column, one "IIIII" item in the second and one "11111" in the third. What should happen if you move the second "WWWWW" item to the second column? The widget will need to expand itself. How would you compute the required overall geometry? And how would you manage the animation? What you want is not impossible, but the problem is that your approach doesn't consider all required aspects.
